# How to add placeholder in input field by javascript using fields ID

Tags: javascript, wordpress, input

How to add a placeholder in the input field by javascript using the field's ID? The form fields are made with a plguin (Wordpress) and I am not getting that folder/file where the code located. SO, can someone help me input placeholder on login fields by JS or JQ?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you are looking for:

```js
const myInput = document.querySelector('#someInputId');
myInput.placeholder = 'Some placeholder';
```

```html
<input id="someInputId" />
```

Comment: Is there any other way to do it? Because it's not working on my site.

Comment: Why it's not working, you have the ID, so document.querySelector(ID); gets the element or not?

Comment: <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" class="input" value="" size="20">

Comment: This is the input field code so I took id "user_login" and placed on both id word in your code

Comment: const myInput = document.querySelector('#user_login');
myInput.placeholder = 'Some placeholder';
<input id="user_login" />

Comment: You shouldn't write <input id="user_login" />, You already have this input. I wrote this in the example to show how it works

Comment: Oh, wait checking